# Cypress long automation script crashes the Chrome browser with Aw Snap Error

Tags: typescript, automation, cypress

I am having a browser crash problem in cypress. 
My automation script is somewhat long process and due to which after it runs couple of scenario. Everytime when it tries to run the third scenario the browser crashes and shows the below screen.

[image]

and some times it gets timeout and throws 440 unknown code error.

[image]

If I move my 1st scenario then also the same behaviour. Everytime 1st and 2nd executes perfectly but from the 3rd all tests fails.

Does anyone face the similar kind of issue?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Cypress has two running modes: debugging/development mode, started with `cypress open`, and a test running mode, started with `cypress run`.

`cypress run` has a few key differences from `cypress open`. The most obvious one is that `cypress run` is headless. It starts an Electron browser in the background and performs all your tests.

This is not the only difference. When running with `cypress open`, Cypress takes regular DOM snapshots for debugging purposes, as you are probably aware. This is implemented with [what has been described](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/431#issuecomment-320082677) as a controlled memory leak; if you have a single test that runs for too long using `cypress open`, the memory will continue to climb until Chrome eventually crashes.

---

If your tests work fine with `cypress run` and not with `cypress open`, then your issue is very likely memory. If this is the case, you have two options which can help.

First, you can reduce the number of snapshots kept in memory. Your `cypress.json` file in your root Cypress folder allows you to set custom values for various settings. `numTestsKeptInMemory` defaults to something like 30, but you can reduce it to 10, 5, or even 0. At 0 you will not get any DOM snapshots. The memory usage will still climb, but it will climb at a much slower rate.

```
{
    "numTestsKeptInMemory": 0
}
```

Second, you can and should split your one large test file into multiple smaller test files. As of version 3.0.0, [Cypress runs each test file in its own render process](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/681). This allows Cypress to clean up after each test, effectively fixing the memory issue as long as your individual files are small enough.

---

If neither of these fix your issue then you may be dealing with another bug, such as [this one](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1906). If you cannot find your issue on [the Github tracker](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues), you may want to consider [reporting it](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/new?template=bug_report.md).

Comment: Great explanation!. Thanks Wade. Let me try your given solution will get back to you soon.

Comment: Hi Wade, Could you please guide me how to execute the cypress run command. 
I have tried "npm run cypress:run" but it says missing scripts.

Comment: Also tried "cypress run" but it says cypress is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: Below, changes in cypress.json works for me as of now. 

{
    "numTestsKeptInMemory": 0
}

Comment: @PrashantKankhara Did you download Cypress from cypress.io, or did you install it via NPM?

Comment: If you installed it via NPM, navigate to the install folder in a command prompt and then use the following command: `node_modules\.bin\cypress run`

Comment: If you installed by downloading the package from cypress.io, you may need to instead [install Cypress via npm](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#npm-install) to use `cypress run`. I can't seem to figure out a way to make Cypress start in headless mode using the cypress.io download.

Comment: Installed using "npm install"

Comment: Alright, see the above comment about using `cypress run` if you installed with NPM.

Comment: Thanks again Wade. I got the way to run command "cypress run". By test script has various scenario and it fails eventually running long eventhough the solution using "numTestsKeptInMemory:0" works when running 3 tests but it fails after few more scripts again. I tried running "cypress run" it works there . So, can you guide more on this?

Comment: As I said in my response, the other solution is to separate your tests into multiple self-contained test files. You can use the `fixtures` folder in your project to put code to be included in every test, such as helper functions.

Comment: You will eventually run into problems in any case while developing if you put all your tests in one file.

Comment: Correction: You can use `support/index.js` to add helper functions. `fixtures` is something different.

Comment: My testcases works well after that "numTestsKeptInMemory" change to 0 but now after few months one of my testcase is taking long time to execute which eventually crashes my browser again back to Aw, Snap error. Apart from this is there any other properties to set to prevent browser crashing ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You can use `cypress run` instead of `cypress open` for your tests, but that's probably not optimal. My suggestion here would be to break your one large test into a few smaller tests.